# What does the comma mean in "where $x\neq 0$, $y\neq 0$"?

Tags: group-theory, notation

In this context

“A binary operation * is defined on the set of all ordered pairs (*x*,*y*) of real numbers, where x ≠ 0, y ≠ 0

The operation is given as:

(*a*,*b*)*(*c*,*d*) = (*ad* + *bc*,*bd*)”

Does that mean that neither *x* nor *y* can be zero. Or does it mean that one of *x*, *y* *can* be zero, but does not have to be?

Sorry, to clarify I’m referring to the comma in **x ≠ 0, y ≠ 0**

Comment: It means neither $x$ nor $y$ can be zero. The comma is "and" in this case.

Comment: @angryavian So that means this set does not have an identity element? Because a possible identity element would have been (0,1). But since neither x not y can be zero, this ordered pair is not part of the set, and so isn’t an identity element. Am I missing something?

Comment: As it's written the comma does mean "and". Are you sure you have transcribed the definition correctly?

Comment: @s.xw no that is not true. Zero is the identity in some groups but not all groups. Consider for example the group $g=\{1,-1\}$ with the group operation being ordinary multiplication. Zero is not in this group but it does have an identity element.

Comment: @EthanBolker This is the start to a question on an A-level maths paper. I've double checked to see if it was transcribed correctly. One part of the question asks you to find the identity element (and then the inverse of (a,b)). The mark scheme gives (0 , 1) as the identity element. Is that not only true if the comma is taken to mean "or"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition "where $x\neq 0,y\neq 0$" would normally mean *both* $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, so the comma means "and".  However, that interpretation doesn't seem to make much sense in context.  For instance, it would mean that this $*$ is not actually a binary operation on the set described at all, since $(1,1)*(1,-1)=(0,-1)$ is not an element of the set.

So, probably there is an error in the statement here.  I would guess that the intended statement is actually only to require that $y\neq 0$ (rather than both being nonzero, or at least one being nonzero).  That's just a guess, though, and lacking additional context, there is no way to know for sure without asking whoever wrote it originally.

Comment: I think it's a pretty good guess, though.

Comment: Does "set" mean the same as "group" in group theory?

Comment: @s.xw: No, not at all.  A set is just any collection at all, with no particular binary operation chosen.

Comment: @EricWofsey After rechecking the definition of "binary operation",  and the mark scheme which follows the reasoning that only one is nonzero to deduce the identity element, I think the question paper must follow your interpretation. Thank you for helping to clarify with that example. Really feel sorry for the pupils who had to sit this paper though...